# PowerBuilder Tabpage

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a Tabpage (tab_1) in PowerBuilder, What I want to do is Insert a Tab Page in that (tab_1) whenever I click a button. It will insert tab pages thru coding. I want to replicate whatever (Right Click Insert Tab page does...) Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a tabpage at runtime, you need to

- prepare a visual userobject that contains the controls (and preferably the processing code)
- use the `OpenTab()` or `OpenTabWithParm()` methods to add a new page to the Tab with the desired content when the button click occurs.

Answer (score 0):

To create tabpage dynamically, you can use any of the following method.

1. tabcontrolname.OpenTab ( userobjectvar, userobjecttype, index )
2. tabcontrolname.OpenTabWithParm ( userobjectvar, parameter, index )

Please Refer : 
http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/CAIDCDGJ.htm